# Make DIV and UL act like a SELECT element

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is replace the "my dropdown" text of the `<span class="hideSelect">` element with the text of the clicked `<li>`, in order to make it work like a `<select>` element.

CSS:

```
.myDrop {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max- width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mydrop ul {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mydrop ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.mydrop ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".mydrop").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".mydrop>ul").stop().slideToggle(500);
    $(document).click(function(){
      $(".mydrop>ul").hide();
    });
  });
  $(".mydrop>ul li").click(function () {
    $(".hideSelect").hide();
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="mydrop">
        <div class="myDrop">
          <span class="hideSelect">
              <span id="caption">my dropdown</span>
              <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul id="options">
          <li class="visilkl">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</li>
          <li>Burger, Shake and a Smile</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what part of the code you need to hide??? div with id mydrop or myDrop?

Comment: hope you're using select box , right?? i wanna do the same thing like happens on select box when we click, visible thing hides and the clicked thing comes visible on the select box.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to hide the content of `<span class="hideSelect">` so the `my dropdown` will be hidden **once** a value has been selected from the `<ul>`.

You could achieve this like so:

```
$(".mydrop").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".mydrop>ul").stop().slideToggle(500);
    $(document).click(function() {
      $(".mydrop>ul").hide();
    });
});
$(".mydrop>ul li").click(function() {
    $(".hideSelect").text(this.innerHTML); //Get the text from the clicked li and write it to the span with class hideSelect
})
```

The HTML does not change

For a demo, see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f99t7jcg/1/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little change to your html but this allows the JS to work.

So i added a span around the "my dropdown" so its now

`<span class="dropText">my dropdown</span>`

This allows us to change the next a little easier.

Once you have done that you can add this to your page and it should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showingDropdown = false;

    $(".hideSelect").click(function() {
        showingDropdown = true;
        $(".mydrop ul").show();
    });

    $(".mydrop ul li").click(function() {
        if(showingDropdown) {
            showingDropdown = false;
            $(".dropText").text($(this).text());
            $(".mydrop ul").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle of it working](https://jsfiddle.net/hammy2899/wu0cpeo1/)

Answer (score 0):

There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/athrpcxs/

Is this what you need?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="mydrop">
        <div class="myDrop">
          <span class="hideSelect">
              <span id="caption">my dropdown</span>
              <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul id="options">
          <li class="visilkl">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</li>
          <li>Burger, Shake and a Smile</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
          <li>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".mydrop").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".mydrop>ul").stop().slideToggle(500);
    $(document).click(function(){
      $(".mydrop>ul").hide();
    });
  });
  $(".mydrop > ul li").click(function () {
    $("#caption").text($(this).text());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().hide();
})
```